# Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED (com.google.android.play:core

Tags: java, android, localbroadcastmanager

I am getting a crash with my android apps. Which shows security exception with the targetSDKVersion 34.

How to resolve this. The error is showing as below (playcore library) **com.google.android.play.core.listener.zzc.zzb (com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:3)**

Note: I am using the LocalBroadcastManager in my app. Is this issue raised because of this?

Code:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter)
```

Error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
pck: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3057)

android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver (ContextWrapper.java:755)
com.google.android.play.core.listener.zzc.zzb (com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:3)
com.google.android.play.core.listener.zzc.zzf (com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:4)
com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzf.registerListener (com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:1)
fragments.Summaryfragment.onCreate (Summaryfragment.java:144)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:2949)

androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:246)
ActionBarFragmentActivity.onStart (ActionBarFragmentActivity.java:358)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1582)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Android 14 there is a requirement to specify the export flag when registering context-registered receivers - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#runtime-receivers-exported

> Apps and services that target Android 14 and use context-registered receivers are required to specify a flag to indicate whether or not the receiver should be exported to all other apps on the device either `RECEIVER_EXPORTED` or `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`, respectively.

If your `MessageReceiver` is supposed to be called only by the components within your app, then you should use `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`. If it is supposed to be accessible to components beyond your own app - use `RECEIVER_EXPORTED`.

Now, before you try to apply the change, you have to migrate from the deprecated `LocalBroadcastManager` since it does not allow you to specify the export flag. I would advise you to use `ContextCompat` class to register the receiver now. Your code should look more or less like this now:

```kotlin
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
    this,
    mMessageReceiver,
    filter,
    ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
)
```

Now this code will not throw an error now, but **it still might not work** - Android 14 introduced another restriction when it comes to sending implicit intents to non-exported components: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#safer-intents

In your case, if you're using the `RECEIVER_EXPORTED` flag, you should not worry about this change in this context.

If you're using `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` (like on the code above) and you're calling the `MessageReceiver` with an implicit intent, probably using intent action:

```kotlin
context.sendBroadcast(Intent(YOUR_APP_ACTION))
```

then you should make that `Intent` explicit, because otherwise it would not be received on Android 14+:

```kotlin
context.sendBroadcast(
    Intent(YOUR_APP_ACTION).apply {
        setPackage(context.packageName)
    }
)
```

Specifying a package makes the `Intent` explicit - the non-exported `MessageReceiver` is able to receive those intents now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From which sdk or imports the ContextCompat is used. If I try this register reciver is not available,

Comment: shall i use this.registerReceiver(
    this,
    mMessageReceiver,
    filter,
    ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
)

Comment: For unregister shall I use context.unregister? or ContextCompact.unregister?

Comment: I think it needs to have minSDK as 26

Comment: I have updated the answer with the import for `ContextCompat`. You should use `ContextCompat` to register the receiver. To unregister, use `context.unregisterReceiver`.

Comment: androidx.core.content.ContextCompat; it not showing registerReceiver.

Comment: What do you mean 'not showing'? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#registerReceiver(android.content.Context,android.content.BroadcastReceiver,android.content.IntentFilter,int) Are you sure You've passed matching arguments for the function signature? Also you need the following dependency: `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'`

Comment: I an using java. But the above shows ktx

Comment: Sure, here's the dependency for java: `implementation "androidx.core:core:1.12.0"`

Comment: I have modified LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent); to getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent); is ot fine or need to set the packagename for the application context?

Comment: It depends on whether the intent is explicit or implicit and whether the receiver you've registered has the `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` flag. How does the `Intent` in the `sendBroadcast` look like? And did you use `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` when calling `registerReceiver`?

Comment: Setting an event list got changed and it is a string.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the `Intent` created like this: `new Intent(MessageReceiver::class);` or rather like this `new Intent("ACTION_STRING");`?

Comment: In one Activity class new Intent("ACTION_STRING");

Comment: Ok, and have You used `RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` flag in `registerReceiver`?

Comment: Yes. I have used RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED in this case

Comment: Then the answer is yes, you have to specify the `package` for the `Intent("ACTION_STRING");` you are creating: `intent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255760/discussion-between-sejn-and-sweak).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `Android 14` (API 34) are required to specify a `flag` to indicate whether or not the receiver should be exported to all other apps on the device

Follow the steps

**Step 1** : Create an instance of `BroadcastReceiver`

```
val br: BroadcastReceiver = MyBroadcastReceiver()
```

**Step 2** : Create an instance of `IntentFilter`

```
val filter = IntentFilter(YOUR_BROADCAST_FILTER)
```

**Step 3** : Choose whether the broadcast receiver should be exported and visible to other apps on the device. If this receiver is listening for broadcasts sent from the system or from other apps—even other apps that you own—use the RECEIVER_EXPORTED flag. If instead this receiver is listening only for broadcasts sent by your app, use the RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag.

```
val listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps = false
    val receiverFlags = if (listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps) {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
    } else {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    }
```

**Step 4** : Register the receiver by calling `registerReceiver()`

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, br, filter, receiverFlags)
```

> Caution: If the broadcast receiver is exported, other apps could send
> unprotected broadcasts to your app

Comment: ContextCompat is from which import? How it looks lile in MyBroadcastReceiver.java? Is the same from the Local broadcast? For sendBroadcast and unRegisterReceiver how it will be handles?

Comment: You can unregister like ```unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)``` as before