# Android error: Cannot resolve method 'registerReceiver' in 'ContextCompat'

Tags: java, android, android-14

**BACKGROUND**

Migrating Android Java project from Android SDK-13 to Android SDK level 14. I need to register some Broadcast related Flags.

According to several online documentation, I should use 'ContextCompat.registerReceiver(...)' to register the broadcasting services.

**PROBLEM**

Even though, under `dependencies`, in my `build.gradle` file, I have mentioned:

```
   implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0'
```

And after importing it in the activity as:

```
   import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

I am unable to find the method '`registerReceiver()`' as can be seen in the attached screenshot below.

[image]

**QUESTION**

1. Am I still missing any dependencies?
2. Do I need to upgrade any specific library?
3. Is there any alternative solution to register the receiver with required flags  so that the activity doesn't crash on Android devices with SDK-14?

**REFERENCES**

- [Android-14 Behaviour Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#java)
- [Fatal Exception for RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371855/fatal-exception-java-lang-securityexception-one-of-receiver-exported-or-receive)
- The ContextConpat source file (package and constructor). See there is no results for 'register'

[image]

Comment: You will see `registerReceiver()` in [the source code to `ContextCompat` in `1.12.0`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/core/core/1.12.0-source/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.java.html). Either your IDE is confused or whatever that `ContextCompat` symbol is resolving to is not the actual `ContextCompat`. You might try view-source to see what that `ContextCompat` is referencing.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is the package: `package androidx.core.content;` and indeed, it doesn't have the `'registerReceiver'` method in it.

Comment: Run a Gradle dependency report and see what version of `core` you wound up using.

Comment: @CommonsWare Resolved by upgrading the version of `androidx.appcompat` from `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0` to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1`